# Why can't I show the ð symbol in LaTeX?

Tags: unicode, latex

I can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0278}{\phi}` and then `$ɸ$` to display the ɸ symbol in LaTeX. However, when I try to use:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0360}{\eth}

\begin{document}

$ð$

\end{document}
```

ð doesn't display. Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

- a package which provides the `\eth` macro in the encoding you are using, e.g. `stix`
- the `\eth` macro from this package is, unlike `\phi`, a text macro and not a math macro, so either use it outside of a math environment or surround it with `\text{..}` from the `amsmath` package
- if your tex distribution is not totally out of date, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default since a couple of years

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stix}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0360}{\eth}

\begin{document}

ð

$\text{ð}$

\end{document}
```

or avoid all the trouble and simply use an unicode aware engine like lualatex:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

ð

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried the checked solution, but it was impossible due to the conflict with a template.

Instead, my colleague suggested `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, and then, you can use `\dh` to display ð in both bib and tex files.